# Merging two DataFrames based on indexes from two other DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I'm new to pandas have tried going through the docs and experiment with various examples, but this problem I'm tacking has really stumped me.

I have the following two dataframes (DataA/DataB) which I would like to merge on a per global_index/item/values basis.

```
DataA                      DataB
row  item_id  valueA       row    item_id  valueB
0    x        A1           0      x        B1
1    y        A2           1      y        B2
2    z        A3           2      x        B3
3    x        A4           3      y        B4
4    z        A5           4      z        B5
5    x        A6           5      x        B6
6    y        A7           6      y        B7
7    z        A8           7      z        B8
```

The list of items(item_ids) is finite and each of the two dataframes represent a the value of a trait (trait A, trait B) for an item at a given global_index value.

The global_index could roughly be thought of as a unit of "time"

The mapping between each data frame (DataA/DataB) and the global_index is done via the following two mapper DFs:

```
DataA_mapper
global_index  start_row  num_rows
0             0          3
1             3          2
3             5          3


DataB_mapper
global_index  start_row  num_rows
0             0          2
2             2          3
4             5          3
```

Simply put for a given global_index (eg: 1) the mapper will define a list of rows into the respective DFs (DataA or DataB) that are associated with that global_index.

For example, for a global_index value of 0:

- In DF DataA rows 0..2 are associated with global_index 0
- In DF DataB rows 0..1 are associated with global_index 0

Another example, for a global_index value of 2:

- In DF DataB rows 2..4 are associated with global_index 2
- In DF DataA there are no rows associated with global_index 2

The ranges [start_row,start_row + num_rows) presented do not overlap each other and represent a unique sequence/range of rows in their respective dataframes (DataA, DataB)

In short no row in either DataA or DataB will be found in more than one range.

---

I would like to merge the DFs so that I get the following dataframe:

```
row   global_index  item_id   valueA   valueB
0     0             x         A1        B1
1     0             y         A2        B2
2     0             z         A3        NaN
3     1             x         A4        B1
4     1             z         A5        NaN
5     2             x         A4        B3
6     2             y         A2        B4
7     2             z         A5        NaN
8     3             x         A6        B3
9     3             y         A7        B4
10    3             z         A8        B5
11    4             x         A6        B6
12    4             y         A7        B7
13    4             z         A8        B8
```

In the final datafram any pair of **global_index/item_id** there will ever be either:

1. a value for both valueA and valueB
2. a value only for valueA
3. a value only for valueB

With the requirement being if there is only one value for a given global_index/item (eg: valueA but no valueB) for the last value of the missing one to be used.

Comment: Can you share some example data in a format that makes it easy to use?

Comment: @AMC - sure I can do that, though do the examples above not convey the structure - the bit i'm having problems with is relating the mapper frame to the dataframesA/B - as they are the only relationship the dataA/B frames have with the global_index.

Comment: In the merged DF, I did not get how did you get the ```valueA``` values when ```global_index  == 2```  even if it was not listed in the ```DataA_mapper``` table, can you explain me that @Lucinda Rigetti ?

Comment: I am not really understanding the last requirement. So for global_index 2 there are no associated rows in DataA but when they merge you are showing valueA as A4, A2, and A5 for that global index. What is the logic for that?

Comment: @K753 I aggree.  Is the expected output above correct for the data given in this problem?

Comment: @K753 and Sidou Mahmoud I've added more clarifications, hopefully  it will resolve any outstanding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can create the `'global_index'` column using the function `pd.cut`:

```
for df, m in [(df_A, map_A), (df_B, map_B)]:

    bins = np.insert(m['num_rows'].cumsum().values, 0, 0) # create bins and add zero at the beginning
    df['global_index'] = pd.cut(df['row'], bins=bins, labels=m['global_index'], right=False)
```

Next, you can use outer join to `merge` both data frames:

```
df = df_A.merge(df_B, on=['global_index', 'item_id'], how='outer')
```

And finally you can use functions `groupby` and `ffill` to fill missing values:

```
for val in ['valueA', 'valueB']:
    df[val] = df.groupby('item_id')[val].ffill()
```

Output:

```
   item_id  global_index  valueA  valueB
0        x             0      A1      B1
1        y             0      A2      B2
2        z             0      A3     NaN
3        x             1      A4      B1
4        z             1      A5     NaN
5        x             3      A6      B1
6        y             3      A7      B2
7        z             3      A8     NaN
8        x             2      A6      B3
9        y             2      A7      B4
10       z             2      A8      B5
11       x             4      A6      B6
12       y             4      A7      B7
13       z             4      A8      B8
```

Comment: excellent solution, works perfectly! and thank-you for the correcting the data in the question.

Comment: One minor question - if we were to add one more row to the DataA_mapper (or the other mapper) where we duplicate the global_index but give another start/num_rows range eg: (3, 8, 2) and we add the appropriate rows in DataA.    _____

When I run this, I get the following error: "Categorical categories must be unique" on the call to cut. What would be the correct way to solve this to ensure that the valueA,valueB for an item_id is always set to the last set of values defined by  the global_index/startidx/num_row combo?   __

I'd be happy to create another question, if you have a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out, since I don't have any good test data, but I think something like this should work. Basically what this is doing is, rather than trying to pull off some sort of complicated join, it is building a series of lists to hold your data, which you can then put back together into a final dataframe at the end.

```
DataA.set_index('row')
DataB.set_index('row')

#we're going to create the new dataframe from scratch, creating a list for each column we want
global_index = []
AValues = []
AIndex = []
BValues = []
BIndex = []

for indexNum in totalIndexes:
    #for each global index, we get the total number of rows to extract from DataA and DataB
    AStart = DataA_mapper.loc[DataA_mapper['global_index']==indexNum, 'start_row'].values[0]
    ARows = DataA_mapper.loc[DataA_mapper['global_index']==indexNum, 'num_rows'].values[0]
    AStop = AStart + Arows

    BStart = DataB_mapper.loc[DataB_mapper['global_index']==indexNum, 'start_row'].values[0]
    BRows = DataB_mapper.loc[DataB_mapper['global_index']==indexNum, 'num_rows'].values[0]
    BStop = BStart + Brows


    #Next we extract values from DataA and DataB, turn them into lists, and add them to our data
    AValues = AValues + list(DataA.iloc[AStart:AStop, 1].values)
    AIndex = AIndex + list(DataA.iloc[AStart:AStop, 0].values)
    BValues = BValues + list(DataB.iloc[BStart:BStop, 1].values)
    BIndex = BIndex + list(DataA.iloc[AStart:AStop, 0].values)

    #Create a temporary list of the current global_index, and add it to our data
    global_index_temp = []
    for row in range(max(ARows,Brows)):
        global_index_temp.append(indexNum)
    global_index = global_index + global_index_temp


#combine all these individual lists into a dataframe
finalData = list(zip(global_index, AIndex, BIndex, AValues, BValues))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = finalData, columns = ['global_index', 'item1', 'item2', 'valueA', 'valueB'])

#lastly you just need to merge item1 and item2 to get your item_id column
```

I've tried to comment it nicely so that hopefully the general plan makes sense and you can follow along and correct my mistakes or rewrite it your own way.

Comment: If you're going to write so much code, why not use correct naming conventions? Also, why the `list(.values)` instead of `.tolist()`? Why are you converting the result of the zip to a tuple? This is quite undiomatic...

Comment: (1) definitely a fair point with my lack of naming conventions (2) because I just started learning pandas a week ago and didn't know I could, thanks for the suggestion (3) is there a more recommended way of turning multiple lists into a pandas dataframe? list(zip()) is the way that I learned in this tutorial that was linked to directly from the official pandas website:
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb

Comment: (3) Zip is fine, it's just that I think the `list()` is unnecessary.